# getting the path input file at run time

Tags: java, file

I have my main class a one more class which takes a file path(absolute) as string. How can i initialize  this filepath with its value. No  hard codeing of  the path of file is required.

My package stcture is

```
src
 com.xyz.pk1
data  //input.txt is present in this dir



public class Test{

  public static void main(){
   String filepath = "" //TODO :no hard coding like C:\filename.txt
   MyClass c = new new Myclass(filepath);
 }

}
```

EDIT:
My folder struct is as follows NOW:

```
src
data
   input.txt
```

now if i type following code inside a class placed in src

```
 Test.class.getResourceAsStream("data/Input.csv");
```

I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)
```

any clues??

Comment: Your question is too vague at the moment - you haven't explained where you want the filename to come from at all, nor is your program valid (as your `main` method doesn't take `String[]`, and you've got a double `new`, and you haven't shown `MyClass`, and you're inconsistent in the capitalization of that name.) Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question - the more effort you spend on writing a good question, the more likely it is to get a good answer.

Comment: file name is input.txt that is present inside data folder

Comment: You said you didn't want the name to be hard-coded - are you happy for the "data" and "input.txt" part to be hard-coded, just not the full name? What do you want to happen if the program is run from elsewhere? Are the class files ever going to end up in a jar file, and if so would the input.txt file be in the jar file too?

Comment: i dont want it to be hard coded like  C:\data\input.txt.The file is present in data folder and data folder is parallel to src.So what  i want it from main class i get the absulute path of file and then pass it to "MYclass"

Comment: Your `src` folder is presumably only going to be present on *your* machine though - how is this going to be deployed on *non-developer* machines?

Comment: For your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9373126/2): Please compare your folder structure with the folder structure in my answer - and compare the resource location strings.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the absolute path of the file

```
File f = new File("<your file>");
String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably will not have a `src` dir after building. It will be `classes` or `bin` or such. If your data is static the resources folder should be merged with the classes folder (this is the default for Maven).

I.e. the structure could be:

```
/
    com
        xyz
            pk1
                Test.class
    data
        input.txt
```

Then you could get an URL pointing to the resource with

```
YourClassName.class.getResource("/data/input.txt");
```

or an `InputStream` with

```
YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/input.txt");
```

That is the way to go for *static* resources. You can even package the resource within a jar. If you want to modify the file than it would be the wrong method.

Comment: yes.But the problem is that the second class "My class" needs a absulute file name.So from main method i somehow need to get the absolute file

Comment: Ok, then it depends if run from a jar or exploded. `getResource` gives you an `URL` which can (and will be here) a file URL, i.e. the absolute path. When run from an jar this will not be helpful to classes that depend on physical files. Then you could add another directory parallel to the jar to the classpath and this method will still work.

Comment: @user93796: *Why* does the second class need an absolute filename? Can you just fix that?

Comment: I can .But is it a good practice?What if i want that code  to reused?Like lets say some days after today i want to pass some file presnt at diff location

Comment: @user93796: Yes, it would absolutely be good practice to remove the dependency on absolute filenames. Assuming the code only needs to *read* the file, you should potentially change it to accept a `Reader` or an `InputStream`. (`Reader` is more appropriate for text data.)

Comment: What if i want i want to write something to file too as well?in that case reader wont work

Comment: As you don't present very much code and context we had to made assumptions. "data/input.txt" lead to the assumption of read-only resources.

Answer (score 0):

You many Choose `JFileChooser` to select your file and then set 
`JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();`
and 
then 
`File file=chooser.getSelectedFile();`